# How to check the installed Qt version on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, qt

Is there a command to check the version of the installed Qt on Mac OS X. My Mac OS X version is 10.6.7.

**Eidt: Update the status 10/28/2011**

When running /usr/sbin/system_profiler SPFrameworksDataType, the version of the QTkit is 7.6.6.

The value of the macro QT_VERSION_STR in qglobal.h is "4.7.2".

I'm confused why the two version strings are different? Obviously, the version string "4.7.2" is what I want.

Thanks,
Jeffrey

Comment: Does OS X have Qt installed by default? 10.6.8 doesn't seem to.

Comment: I installed it myself long time ago. I want to verify the installed version now.

Comment: For clarification: by "qt", do you mean [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) or [QuickTime](http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IF you speak about programming here...: At compile time you can check Qt's version with `QT_VERSION_STR`. During runtime you can use `qVersion()`. Obviously, the version you build you application with does not always match the version you run it with.

Comment: worth to mention in console if qmake is within PATH envoirment variable you can call qmake -v and It will print out version

Answer (score 17):

If you installed with brew, just do...

`brew info qt`
or
`brew info qt5`

Update:

Doing it this way will cut out all the extra stuff and only show versions.

`brew list --versions qt`
or
`brew list --versions qt5`

Here's a nice cheatsheet for brew, btw: http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/homebrew.html

Answer (score 14):

Go to your "*Applications>>Tools*" folder and launch the **System-Profiler**. Look at "*Software>>Frameworks>>QTKit*". There you will find the version.

To get in in a terminal (to use it from Java for example) execute the following command:

```
  /usr/sbin/system_profiler SPFrameworksDataType
```

There you will find something like this:

```
  QTKit:

    Version: 7.7
    Last Modified: 13.04.11 16:02
    Kind: Universal
    64-Bit (Intel): Yes
    Get Info String: QTKit 7.7, Copyright 2003-2011, Apple Inc.
    Location: /System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework
    Private: No
```

In XCode there should be an environment-variable available.

Comment: Ah, see i read 'qt' as meaning Qt, the portable GUI toolkit. You have read it as meaning QuickTime. I'll ask.

Comment: Oops - but qt Framework you get also with this mechanism. I'll correct my answer in about an hour.

Answer (score 9):

On terminal:

> `qmake -v`

It should return versions of QMake and Qt.

Something like:

> `QMake version 3.0`
>
> `Using Qt version 5.6.2 in /Users/thiago/anaconda/lib`

Answer (score 2):

If you can find where Qt's headers are installed, `qglobal.h` contains a define for `QT_VERSION_STR`. You can simply grep for that.

Answer (score 1):

cd to the include directory where your qt headers are located and then...

```
grep --include=\*.h -rnw ./ -e "QT_VERSION_STR"
```

which should output something like...

`./QtCore/qglobal.h:40:#define QT_VERSION_STR   "5.4.2"`

Answer (score 1):

If installed via brew, this will get the version into the variable `QT_VERSION`

```
QT_VERSION=`brew list --versions qt5 | sed -En -e 's/qt ([0-9._]+).*/\1/p'`
```

You can then invoke it thusly:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/${QT_VERSION}/bin/qmake
```